# Can we get the specific formulation form of thin plate regression spline in GAM?

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, splines, mgcv

In `mgcv` package, the default smoother is thin plate regression spline. After building a GAM model, can we "write" the formula form of the thin plate regression spline? For example, in the form of `y = k*x + b`.

Comment: Welcome to CV T X. As I understand it, Simon Wood wrote the critical text on this topic (specific to `mgcv` anyway): Wood, S. N. (2003). [Thin plate regression splines](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/attachment/2063352/0/tprs.pdf). *Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series B (Statistical Methodology)*, 65(1), 95–114.

Comment: A GAM is called a "non-parametic model" for a reason.